# In NUnit 3 when using TestFixtureSource is there a SetUp/TearDown that is called before/after all the instances of the fixture?

Tags: nunit, nunit-3.0

So `OneTimeSetUp`/`OneTimeTearDown` is called before/after every instance of the fixture.

Do we have something that is called before/after all the instances of the fixture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends where the `OneTimeSetUp / OneTimeTearDown` methods are located. If they are in the code of the test fixture itself, then they are called before and after the tests are run in each instance.This is necessary, since they might be doing something that affects that instance.

OTOH, if you put them into a `SetUpFixture` in the same namespace as the test fixture, then they are called once before and after all the tests within that namespace. If you want the affect to be isolated to all instances of a certain fixture, then put the code into a namespace by itself.